# retrieving full url with anchor in rails 3 and backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have a url like this: /hello/world#/lol/backbone

I'd like to get access, in ruby, to the full, entire path. I'd normally do something like this: `request.fullpath` but that returns only `/hello/world` and leaves off the `#/lol/backbone/`

Been Googling for awhile. Can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the fragment in your server code, the URL fragment (`#/lol/backbone`) is a client-side issue. The browser will interpret the fragment but it will not send it to your server.

If you need the fragment then you'll have to convert it to a parameter by intercepting your link with a bit of JavaScript, then the server could see something like

```
/hello/world?frag=/lol/backbone
```

and you could pull the fragment out of `params[:frag]`. This does of course assume that your JavaScript link interceptor will get run, that's not guaranteed so your server-side code should be prepared for a missing `params[:frag]`.